# Disable Quasar slider arrow key events

Tags: javascript, range, slider, vuejs3, quasar-framework

When doing a slider input the arrow keys are bound to that slider, even after the mouse event is finished. Using arrowLeft/arrowRight steps the q-slider one value and stops the key event.
I'm using the arrow keys for something else in my application (`document.addEventListener("onkeydown",(e: Event)=>{//...}`) and want to disable this behavior. On normal HTML sliders, I can do `<input type="range" onkeydown="event.preventDefault();return true;" />` to disable this, but this does not work on the Quasar sliders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by capturing all key events on the document.

```ts
    document.addEventListener("keydown", (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
        doButtonPress(e)
    }, true)
```